# flutter firestore node.js not generating function folder with node.js in it

Tags: node.js, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have selected the project and there should be a folder generated for me containing a node.js file. However there was an error.

A functions directory will be created in your project with a Node.js
package pre-configured. Functions can be deployed with firebase deploy.

Error: HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission

I Have no idea what to do to fix this.
Help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this related https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17742 ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
The issue was a directory issue where i had another project that was set as the main directory which was link to my other google account causing an error.